# How to groupby and get average using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How to groupBy `category` and get the average using underscore?

I have an array of objects. It should be grouped by `category` and average for `Analytics` is calculated from the `val` property ie., 1+2 => 3. 3/total number of categories. So, 3/2 => 1.5

Expected Output: `{ Analytics: 1.5 }`

```
[{
  area:"Digital",
  category:"Analytics",
  qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
  type:"Reorganize",
  userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
  val:1
},
{
  area:"Digital",
  category:"Analytics",
  qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
  type:"Reorganize",
  userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
  val:2
}]
```

Thanks

Comment: How to call 'answers' property. Please refer the below code and advise,

[
{
_id:"oq8DRjm6uA9mtoJvw",
answers:[
{
  area:"Digital",
  category:"Analytics",
  qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
  type:"Reorganize",
  userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
  val:1
},
{
  area:"Digital",
  category:"Analytics",
  qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
  type:"Reorganize",
  userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
  val:2
}]
}
]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [group the objects by category](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy), then [iterate over all the keys in this resulting object](http://underscorejs.org/#mapObject) and [reduce the values](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce):

```
var types = _.groupBy(array, 'category');
var result = _.mapObject(types, function(val, key) {
  return _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) { 
    return memo + v.val; 
  }, 0) / val.length;
});
```

```js
var array = [{
  area:"Digital",
  category:"Analytics",
  qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
  type:"Reorganize",
  userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
  val:1
},
{
  area:"Digital",
  category:"Analytics",
  qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
  type:"Reorganize",
  userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
  val:2
}];

var types = _.groupBy(array, 'category');
var result = _.mapObject(types, function(val, key) {
  return _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) { 
    return memo + v.val; 
  }, 0) / val.length;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How to call 'answers' property to group by "Category". Please refer the below code and advise, [ { _id:"oq8DRjm6uA9mtoJvw", answers:[ { area:"Digital", category:"Analytics", qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3", type:"Reorganize", userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A", val:1 }, { area:"Digital", category:"Analytics", qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3", type:"Reorganize", userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A", val:2 }] } ]

Comment: Sure. Let me create one more post.