# How to groupBy category array inside an array

Tags: underscore.js

How to groupBy category ***array inside an array*** from ***answers*** property and get the average using underscore?

I have nested array of objects. It should be grouped by category and get average for Analytics is calculated from the val property ie., 1+2 => 3. 3/total number of categories. So, 3/2 => 1.5

Expected Output: { Analytics: 1.5 }

```
[ 
{ _id:"oq8DRjm6uA9mtoJvw", 
answers:[
{
  area:"Digital",
  category:"Analytics",
  qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
  type:"Reorganize",
  userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
  val:1
},
{
  area:"Digital",
  category:"Analytics",
  qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
  type:"Reorganize",
  userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
  val:2
}
],
date:Tue Aug 16 2016 11:13:59
}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to get the average from all the dates, or just average per date? The question is not very clear.

Comment: Just average from category from "Analytics".

Comment: @Tholle - Can you help me with this

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Will there be many objects in an `answers`-array in the main array? I can't help if I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Tholle. Its same like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064019/how-to-groupby-and-get-average-using-underscorejs . Only the difference here is it contains nested array i.e, "answers"

kindly Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the average of the answers in the first object in the array, you can get the answers array,  [group the objects by category](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy), and [iterate over all the keys in this resulting object](http://underscorejs.org/#mapObject), and [reduce the values](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce):

```
var answers = array[0].answers;
var types = _.groupBy(answers, 'category');
var result = _.mapObject(types, function(val, key) {
  return _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) { 
    return memo + v.val; 
  }, 0) / val.length;
});
```

```js
var array = [{ 
  _id:"oq8DRjm6uA9mtoJvw", 
  answers: [
  {
    area:"Digital",
    category:"Analytics",
    qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
    type:"Reorganize",
    userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
    val:1
  },
  {
    area:"Digital",
    category:"Analytics",
    qId:"wRHmpHHGzrYLsCEJ3",
    type:"Reorganize",
    userId:"M4JEJGiPZ8e9om9A",
    val:2
  }],
  date: 'Tue Aug 16 2016 11:13:59'
}];

var answers = array[0].answers;
var types = _.groupBy(answers, 'category');
var result = _.mapObject(types, function(val, key) {
  return _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) { 
    return memo + v.val; 
  }, 0) / val.length;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question correctly...
The simplest solution is to iterate the array and populate another array for each element you inspect.

The array should contain

```
{
categoryName: '',
valueSum: 0,
count: 0
}
```

The algorithm of O(n^2) complexity is the following:

- Get next element of the array
- If the category exist in the temporary array, add the current value to **valueSum** and increment **count**
- If the category doesn't exist add an element to the array using category, value and setting **count** to 1

when you iterated the entire array, start iterating the temp array and divide the **valueSum** / **count**, this will give you for each category the AVG.